Не отрабатывает нажатие мыши по OnMouseDown() в проекте на Unity
Пытаюсь получить хоть какую-то реакцию на нажатие объекта карты.
Сделал проверку на Старте объекта, что функция print работает (в консоле сообщение появляется).
Объект EventSystem у меня есть.
Перелопатил уже кучу текста, но не нашел, что я делаю ни так в таком простом вопросе.
Даже пробовал заново проект создавать, но результат тот же.
Вот мой игровой стол, справа код который должен вызвать отклик на мышку

Вот здесь показываю что скрипт прикрепил к карте


Спасибо за вариант. Но мне именно без коллайдера нужно было. Я пошаманил и проблема исчезла.
Что я поправил я так и не понял.
Но работает перетянивание карты без использования коллайдера.

в описании метода OnMouseDown указано что  для его работы нужен коллайдер
ссылка

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
